# How import data from Paradox .DB file to R?

Tags: r, paradox

How to import data from Paradox .DB file to R?
The question seems simple but I could not find an answer to it. I will be grateful for any tip.

Comment: Have you tried this answer?<br>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14837414/read-dbase-paradox-data-into-r

Comment: Thank you for respond. I tried to use gnumeric but the same as in comments to the answer (your link) I didn't get immediate success on using the gnumeric package